# List un-used ID

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I have a DropDownList that is populated with the primary key of Table A. Table B uses Table A primary key as a foreign key. The foreign key can only be used once.

So currently my list always populates with: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (exists as primary in Table A). Table B is already using keys: 1, 2, 3. When they keys are already existing in Table B, I need them not to populate in the dropdownlist.

I have tried to state in an SQL query, to only populate keys that don't exist in Table B. The query I'm trying, but doesn't work is:

```
SELECT Table_A.Grades_ID FROM Table_A INNER JOIN Table_B ON Table_A_ID = Table_B.Grades_ID WHERE Table_A.Grades_ID != Table_B.Grades_ID
```

How do I get my dropdownlist to not populate keys (data) that already exists in Table B?

Comment: What is the 'grades' table in the 'from' clause? Surely that should be 'table_a'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Just adjust your SQL to exclude the PKey values that already exist in TableB**

```
SELECT Table_A.Grades_ID 
FROM 
  Grades 
  LEFT JOIN Table_B ON Table_A_ID = Table_B.Grades_ID 
WHERE Table_B.Grades_ID Is Null
```

**Alternatively, you may wish to use "not in"**

```
SELECT
  Tables_A.Grades_ID
WHERE 
  Tables_A.Grades_ID not in (Select Grades_ID from Table_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select table_a.grades_id
from table_a left outer join
on table_a.grades_id = table_b.grades_id
where table_b.<some other field> is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Grades_ID FROM Grades WHERE Grades_ID NOT IN (SELECT Grades_ID FROM Table_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Table_A.Grades_ID
from Table_A 
where Table_A.Grades_ID NOT IN (Select Grades_ID from Table_B)